# Calculating the number of scheduled dates within a date range from a Weekly Schedule

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Schedule table with a Worker ID columns Monday to Sunday.  If the contains value greater than 0, it means the Worker is scheduled to work on that day.

How can I efficiently calculate how many days a worker needs to work between a date range?  Currently I'm building a date table and cross joining it with the Schedule table and then generating a 1 or 0 for each date.  Then I sum up the values to get the total.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a3292a/7

This appears to work, but it's relatively slow because of the cross-join.  Is there a better/faster way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try `UNPIVOT` on the WorkSchedule and join to your DateValue query on DateName.. Then you just SUM the values

```
;WITH 
L0 AS (SELECT 1 AS c UNION ALL SELECT 1),
L1 AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L0 A CROSS JOIN L0 B),
L2 AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L1 A CROSS JOIN L1 B),
L3 AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L2 A CROSS JOIN L2 B),
L4 AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L3 A CROSS JOIN L3 B),
Nums AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS i FROM L4),
Schedule AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM    [WorkerSchedule]
    UNPIVOT (
        Working
        FOR [WorkDay] IN ([Sunday], [Monday], [Tuesday], [Wednesday], [Thursday], [Friday], [Saturday])
    ) u
)
SELECT  s.WorkerId, SUM(s.Working) ScheduledDays
FROM    Schedule s
INNER JOIN (SELECT DATENAME(weekday, DATEADD(DAY, i - 1, @StartDate)) AS DateValue
            FROM Nums 
            WHERE i <= 1 + DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @EndDate)) d ON s.[WorkDay] = d.DateValue
WHERE s.Working = 1
GROUP BY s.WorkerId
```

Comment: Thanks, I had to use s.Working > 0 because the column can contain any number (it basically implies how many shifts a Worker has on that day)